# Java ArrayList in ArrayList

Tags: java, rr

I have a question about an ArrayList inside an Arraylist.  It's about multiple worlds with multiple spawns. I want to check every world one by one and save all the spawns of that world in an ArrayList. At the end I have an ArrayList with on every position (every position is a world) another Arraylist containing the spawns of that world.

How can I do this if I don't know how many spawns or worlds there are going to be? I thought of this:

Looking to just one world:

```
public ArrayList<Location> Spawnpoints = new ArrayList<Location>(); 
//ArrayList containing all the spawns of this world).
```

Looking to every single spawn in the world

```
 Spawnpoints.add(new Location(spawnX , spawnY , spawnZ)); 
//Adding every spawn to the ArrayList spawnpoints.
```

So after I looked at a world I have filled the ArrayList spawnpoints with locations. Now I want to add the ArrayList spawnpoints to a new ArrayList worlds. 
After that I will repeat the code above for the next world, untill I have had all the worlds.

EDIT.
I think it's working. I have troubles with getting the size of the list when I only have the name.

So let's say I did this: `allSpawnpoints.put("yourWorld",Spawnpoints);`
Now I want to get the size of the Spawnpoints list for the string yourWorld. Any idea how I can do this?

I tried: `int number = allSpawnpoints.get("yourWorld").size();`
it looks like that isn't working.

I hope someone can help me! Thanks for reading.
Regards.

Comment: `allSpawnpoints.get("yourWorld")` will return a `List<Location>` ..so  its like `List<Location> loc = allSpawnpoints.get("yourWorld"); loc.size()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of an `ArrayList` or `World` objects try using a `Map` of `World` to `List` of `Location`. Something like this:

```
Map<World,List<Location>> allSpawnpoints = new HashMap<World,List<Location>>();
```

Then, after you have created your list of spawnpoints for a `World` put it into your `Map` like this:

```
allSpawnpoints.put(yourWorld,Spawnpoints);
```

... and then move onto the next World.

I would also suggest renaming `Spawnpoints` as `spawnPoints`.

Comment: I added something to my question, can you look into it?

Comment: you have to iterate through the Map object, then you will be able to get each key the value of which you can store to a list and then count the size.

Comment: So like this? for (Entry<String, List<Location>> entry : allSpawnpoints.entrySet())
    {
     if (entry.getKey() == "YourWorld")
     {
      int number = entry.getValue().size();}}

Comment: check [this](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-iterate-over-a-map-in-java/) to see how to iterate map in Java